# Gitlab runner: How to disable using cached .git in runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Every time I run a job in gitlab. It uses cached .git from runner. How can I disable using that?

```
Getting source from Git repository 00:06
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/path/to/project/.git/
```

Answer (score 1):

Change git strategy to `clone`: https://docs.gitlab.com/14.2/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy